# javascript for loop onclick progress bar

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onclick, progress-bar

What is the best way to add an onclick event to a for loop in Javascript? 
I am trying to display a progress bar and below it 3 buttons (£1, £5, £10) which will add their values too the bar each time are clicked, until the bar reaches £100 which is its maximum. 
It is a Fundraiser Meter Campaign.

Comment: You only need to bind 3 onclick events right... once each

Comment: Could you provide some code? Did you try something?

Comment: @CallumLinington Thanks, could you show me how?

Comment: Hi @Maxx I can only do a for loop so far. I know the i++ or the i+=5. I am a beginner in Javascript and didnt cover events yet.

Comment: Look up how to attach and event to a DOM element in javascript. You need to show some sort of research otherwise we can only presume that you are treating us like a code writing service.